# Percentage increase/decrease reading 9% as 90% when putting it in descending order

Tags: sql

I created a new column called 'Percentage' that calculates the percentage increase between Expected and Actual payment. The calculation seems right but when I put it in descending order, 9% is right below 90% when 9% should be at the bottom of the list.

In addition to this, i'd like to remove the additional .00 at the end of each number.

Current code:

```
SELECT [ExpectedPayment]
       ,[TotalActualPayment]
       ,CONCAT(ROUND(((TotalActualPayment-ExpectedPayment)/(ExpectedPayment)*100), 0), '%')  'Percentage'
  FROM DATABASE
ORDER BY PERCENTAGE DESC;
```

Current output:

| ExpectedPayment | TotalActualPayment | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23924.8962 | 46096.44 | 93.00% |
| 24083.0961 | 46355.47 | 92.00% |
| 18937.6445 | 36100.58 | 91.00% |
| 18377.3185 | 20123.11 | 9.00% |
| 17537.915 | 19174.82 | 9.00% |
| 24083.0961 | 45515.82 | 89.00% |
| 26064.4709 | 49300.18 | 89.00% |

Expected output:

| ExpectedPayment | TotalActualPayment | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23924.8962 | 46096.44 | 93% |
| 24083.0961 | 46355.47 | 92% |
| 18937.6445 | 36100.58 | 91% |
| 24083.0961 | 45515.82 | 89% |
| 26064.4709 | 49300.18 | 89% |
| 18377.3185 | 20123.11 | 9% |
| 17537.915 | 19174.82 | 9% |

Comment: Your code would not run in MySQL, so the MySQL tag is confusing.

Comment: Noted, removed the tag.

Comment: So which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest ordering per Gordon's suggestion. You can remove the .000 at the end by casting it as type `int`

```
SELECT [ExpectedPayment]
   ,[TotalActualPayment]
   ,CONCAT(cast(ROUND(((TotalActualPayment-ExpectedPayment)/(ExpectedPayment)*100), 0) as int), '%')  'Percentage' 
FROM DATABASE 
order by (TotalActualPayment-ExpectedPayment)/(ExpectedPayment) desc
```

If you are ok with truncating the result of the expression, you can remove the round statement altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You are ordering by a string, not a number.

I would suggest just ordering by the base calculation:

```
order by (TotalActualPayment-ExpectedPayment)/(ExpectedPayment) desc
```

Comment: Thanks!! That seemed to do the trick. How could I improve it by removing the additional .000 at the end of each number?

Comment: @Meowzz . . . You would format the value using the appropriate formatting method for whatever database you are using.